# Function calls inside jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, plugins

I've nearly this code for defining the plugin instance:

```
$.fn.someplugin = function(opts) {
  $(document).on('click', '.option-1', function() {
    alert(1);
  });
};
```

I use some code like this one to make my plugin work:

```
$('.selector-1').someplugin();
```

So jQuery in this way binds likely one click event listener to the document.

The question is, when I use my plugin multiple times, does it mean that jQuery binds 10 click events to the document?

```
$('.selector-1').someplugin();
$('.selector-2').someplugin();
$('.selector-3').someplugin();
$('.selector-4').someplugin();
$('.selector-5').someplugin();
$('.selector-6').someplugin();
$('.selector-7').someplugin();
$('.selector-8').someplugin();
$('.selector-9').someplugin();
$('.selector-10').someplugin();
```

In this way it binds 10 click listeners - because fn.someplugin is called 10 times, or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it binds 10 click listeners to the `$(document)` object.

Every time you call `someplugin()` it will bind a new listener.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jWjEy/)

---

If you want to add a single click handler to the document (inside of your plugin) you can do this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.someplugin = function(opts) {
       alert("Another someplugin call.");
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.option-1', function() {
       alert(1);
    });
})($);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jWjEy/1/)

Comment: god damn, it's really bad.

Comment: @Steve Why is it really bad? What do you expect?

Comment: I want to minimize event handlers, since there can be more than 200 plugin calls on my page. Performance starts to bog down then.

Comment: @Steve It depends on how your plugin works. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to bind only one time :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.someplugin = function (opts) {
        return $(this).each(function (index, value) {
            $(document)
            .off('click', '.option-1')
            .on('click', '.option-1', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert(1);
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selector-1, .selector-2').someplugin();
});
```

`$(this).each` allows you to bind multiple selectors.

`.off()` unbinds the event if it exists.

**jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/rWYS4/

Comment: I think that the event listener should be moved oustide the plugin instance, but inside the anonymous function. Your example is good enouch, but it's not a performance friendly one.

Comment: Yes. A plugin function 'should' only binds event on options' selectors, not globals selectors.